# Docker volume backup error: Tar: MYCONTAINER_VOLUME: Cannot stat: No such file or directory

Tags: docker

I'm trying to backup my volume as described here in the docker documentation: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes

I'm running the command with the path to the volume:

```
docker run --rm --volumes-from MYCONTAINER -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu tar cvf /backup/backup.tar /var/lib/docker/volumes/MYCONTAINER_VOLUME
```

... and also trying with just the name of my volume

```
docker run --rm --volumes-from MYCONTAINER -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu tar cvf /backup/backup.tar MYCONTAINER_VOLUME
```

but no matter what I get an error like: `tar: MYCONTAINER_VOLUME: Cannot stat: No such file or directory`

This volume was created and linked to the container with `docker-compose` and its using a local driver for the volume.

When I run `docker volume ls` I get:

```
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME

local               MYCONTAINER_VOLUME
```

Can someone please tell me what i'm doing wrong with this?

Answer (score 10):

I figured out what the issue was -

The last part of the command should be the path of the volume mounted in the CONTAINER, not the path of the volume on the HOST.

So basically, the formula for this command should be:

```
docker run --rm --volumes-from MYCONTAINER -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu tar cvf /backup/MY_BACKUP.tar /PATH/INSIDE/CONTAINER/TO/VOLUME/data
```

... and this will create `MY_BACKUP.tar` in the current directory of the HOST.

also, make sure to STOP the container before archiving the volume if its something like postgres like in my case.

Then, to restore the volume if you're using `docker-compose` (since I had trouble with this too because the documentation isn't specific to preexisting containers / volumes created this way)

1) STOP the container

2) Make sure MY_BACKUP.tar is in the root project directory of the HOST

3) run

```
docker run --rm --volumes-from MYCONTAINER -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu bash -c "cd / && tar xvf /backup/MY_BACKUP.tar
```

4) restart container

Hope this helps someone and I'm certainly open to any ideas to streamline this.

Comment: thanks! There's definitely a learning curve with docker that isn't helped by the docs, I think. This wouldn't be the first HOST:CONTAINER mixup I've had.

Comment: how do you find the path to the volume inside the container

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes) assume your container does have a volume associated to your container.
Meaning: your [container was started with a volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#start-a-container-with-a-volume).
Example:

```
$ docker run -d \
  --name devtest \
  --mount source=myvol2,target=/app \
  nginx:latest
```

Check at the very least if you do have volumes created with:

```
docker volume ls
```

Comment: Thanks for asking for the check - I added the results of `docker volume ls` to my question

Comment: Also, not sure if this helps, but this was a volume created and linked to the container with `docker-compose`